# What is difference between status and body column of ApexClass?

Tags: soql, sosl

Query 1 : `SELECT id,name FROM apexclass where (status like 'active')`

this query is returning valid result.

[image]

Query 2 : `SELECT id,name FROM apexclass where (body like 'istest')`
is returning below error.

I can't see any difference between those two column, but if i execute query 2, i am getting below error:

> [object Object]: id, name FROM apexclass where (body like 'istest') ^
>   ERROR at Row:1:Column:39 field 'body' can not be filtered in query
>   call

This error usually comes when we query like this

```
SELECT id,name FROM apexclass where body like 'istest'
```

Comment: Body of Apex class is **like** long text area, and you can not filter long text area fields in SOQL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your question, Status is of type Picklist while Body is a Long Text Area. You can find out all you need to know about the [ApexClass](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_apexclass.htm) object in the SOAP API Developer Guide.

Filtering on Long Text Area fields is not supported. Take a read of [Long Text Field Limitations](http://lc169.blogspot.ie/2013/06/long-text-field-limitations.html) if needed.

An alternative approach to your need would be to make used of the [contains()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm) String method. Something like:

```
List<ApexClass> acsWithBody = new List<ApexClass>();
for(ApexClass ac : [SELECT id, Name, Body FROM ApexClass]) {
    if ac.Body.contains('istest');
    acsWithBody.add(ac);
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `FIND '@isTest' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING ApexClass(Name WHERE Status='Active')`.

Comment: I was trying to get all test classes of another environment using rest by this query 
**SELECT id,name FROM apexclass where body like '@isTest'** 
That's why i need only this query to execute. We cannot query SOSL by  Rest.

Answer (score 0):

You can not put like operator against body field.

However if you want to see what test classes are there you can check under 'Apex Test Execution' --> 'Select Tests'

e.g. http://media.screensteps.me/sherod/pye7gn/apex-test-execution-salesforcecom-unlimited-edition-1.png?1360808765

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to get all test classes of another environment using rest by this query **SELECT id,name FROM apexclass where body like '@isTest'** That's why i need only this query to execute. We cannot query SOSL by Rest.

Now i created one services with this method to get All Test classes.

```
@HttpGet
global static List<TestClass> getTestClasses(){
  List<TestClass> TestClassList = new List<TestClass>();
   ApexClass[] tstClasses = [FIND '@isTest' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING ApexClass(Id, Name ORDER BY Name)][0];            
    if(tstClasses != null){
        for(ApexClass cls : tstClasses){
          TestClass tc = new TestClass();
           tc.Id = cls.Id;
           tc.Name = cls.Name;
           TestClassList.add(tc);
           }
         }
   return TestClassList.size()>0?TestClassList:null;
}


global class TestClass{
        public String Id{get; set;}
        public String Name{get; set;}
    }
```